# Perl regular expression - eliminate

Tags: regex, perl

Am a newbie here. I use glimpse in my Perl script to get the path of files.

For example

```
/home/user/Proj/A/Apps/App.pm
/home/user/Proj/B/Apps.pm
```

I need to fetch the part after `Proj` i.e; the output should be

```
A/Apps/App.pm    
B/Apps.pm
```

Comment: It's a static string, why not just do a substring? No regexes are necessary.

Comment: Using a regex on a path does not sound like the right way to do it. Perl is well equipped with manipulating paths and finding files.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use regex/replace you could do something like:

```
$str =~ s!.*/Proj/!!;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have various options here. When it's always at `/home/user/Proj/`, I prefer the second way. If not, you can use the first way as well. The best way is a `substr` (when its a static length):

```
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s_a = "/home/user/Proj/A/Apps/App.pm";
my $s_b = "/home/user/Proj/B/Apps.pm";

say $s_a =~ s{.*Proj/}{}r;
say $s_b =~ s{.*Proj/}{}r;

say $s_a =~ s{/home/user/Proj/}{}r;
say $s_b =~ s{/home/user/Proj/}{}r;

say substr $s_a, 16;
say substr $s_b, 16;
```

output:

```
A/Apps/App.pm
B/Apps.pm
A/Apps/App.pm
B/Apps.pm
A/Apps/App.pm
B/Apps.pm
```

Comment: The non-destructive substitution `/r` requires version 14 of Perl 5. I've modified your code to reflect that. and I disagree that `substr` is the best solution; can you say why you think it is?

Comment: I prefer it because its a bit safer when you try to manipulate directory names that way. But even more i prefer something complete else. I mean, perl has enough better ways of reading directories and handling with them. For example [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) or [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path). The second link is not for this question here, but its worth a look.

Comment: I think it's *less* safe because you have to get the character count right. It's also not obvious what the code is doing (e.g. removing everything up to `/Proj/`) and needs a comment. The regex is self-explanatory.

Comment: You should always comment your code :P and what if the Directory is something like: `/home/abc/Proj/A/Proj/A` ? But we agreed that its better to use a Module for that, than using Regex or substr.

Comment: No you *shouldn't* always comment your code: you should write code that is self-explanatory. This is bad advice that originates from the bad old days of Fortran, when it was pretty much impossible to write self-explanatory code, and is perpetuated by some backward-thinking tutors. I do lean a little towards using a module, but there's little a module can do that a regex can't (your example is just ambiguous - a regex is fine as long as you know *at which* `/Proj/` to terminate). The main advantage of something like `File::Spec` is maintaining portability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modifiy an existing variable to remove the first part of the path then it's simple: just use the substitution operator `s///` to remove the first part of the string up to `/Proj/`. I've used alternative delimiters `s|||` here to avoid having to escape the slashes in the pattern.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @paths = qw{
  /home/user/Proj/A/Apps/App.pm
  /home/user/Proj/B/Apps.pm
};

for my $path (@paths) {
  $path =~ s|.*/Proj/||;
  print $path, "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
A/Apps/App.pm
B/Apps.pm
```

But if you want to leave your path variable as it is and copy the tail portion to another variable, then I think it's best to use a regular expression to *capture* the wanted part, like this

```
for my $path (@paths) {
  my ($tail) = $path =~ m|/Proj/(.+)|;
  print $tail, "\n";
}
```

The output is identical.

Comment: Thx everyone for u r replies. And one more, I have to get rid of the ".pm" part too. @Borodin

Comment: @AmanVidura: Then you can write `my ($tail) = $path =~ m|/Proj/(.+)\.pm|`